# AES encryption problem: Python pycrypt OFB = C++ Gladman CFB

Tags: c++, python, encryption, aes

While trying to get a python application to talk to a C++ application using an encrypt link, we could not get them to talk.  Trying various combinations of parameters we accidentally found that if we told python to encrypt in OFB mode it would successfully decrypt in the C++ in CFB mode.

Both the python pycrypt library and the C++ Gladman library are highly regarded, so which could be wrong?

Strangely, the first byte seems to decrypt OK when using either OFB or CFB at both ends.  Since the standard test vectors only seem to test the first byte (I'm not an expert on this stuff and might not be understanding the test vectors), is it possible that both algorithms would pass the standard test?

Comment: Update: Python OFB to C++ CFB only works for one block of data, then it turns into gibberish!  Only ECB seems to work properly between these two.  Not very secure!

Comment: Tried a different C++ implementation, got identical data, so it appears to be be pycrypt that's at fault.

Comment: What are these 'standard test vectors'? I'm sure they don't just test the first byte, that would be beyond stupid.

Comment: Links to the libraries would help.

Answer (score 3):

PyCrypto uses 8-bit CFB mode by default. I guess the other end uses block-size CFB mode. The segment size in bits is set by the `segment_size` keyword argument to `AES.new`, for block-size CFB mode it should be `AES.block_size*8`.

For the first block OFB mode is identical to block-size CFB mode.

Comment: I don't understand what is meant by 8-bit CFB mode.  In CFB mode, the output of one block encryption becomes the IV for the next block encryption.  Where is the ambiguity?  There is a good explanation of the modes on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Cipher_feedback_.28CFB.29), if it is not complete perhaps you could add something about this segment size?

Comment: @Richard – CFB is [defined as a family of modes](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38a/sp800-38a.pdf) with parameter _s_ – the segment size. So you can have a segment of 8 bits, and for every cipher output you take only the upper 8 bits to xor with the plaintext. The point being that if you have a one-bit transmission error you get only two bytes incorrect, not two blocks.